# checking value of if conditino isn't printing correct output

Tags: php, if-statement, magento

I am working on a chat room and the condition i want to implement is:
  when user send both file and text message it will return an error.

but this isn't working correct.

this is my code

```
if($_FILES['chat_upload_file']){

                    echo "You are in file checking<br/>";
                    echo $text_message;
                    if($text_messege){
                        echo "It's in IF<br/>";
                        $error = 1;
                        $error_msg = "Either Sender can send file or text";
                        exit(0);
                    }
                    else{

                        echo "it's in else<br/>";
                        exit(0);
}
```

here `$text_messege = "hello user";`

the output that i want is from internal IF : **It's in IF**

but the output is : **It's in else**

Comment: ok i got the error i was checking wrong variable ;)

Comment: Except when you want to handle it with just a message, as that is wrapped in the `$_FILES` condition.  So if that outer IF is false (no file), it never gets to a check for just `$message`.  It's implied that `i want to implement is: when user send both file and text message it will return an error.`  That it's desirable to have a `File` OR a `Message`.  Right now you have a File and a Message, or A File and no Message, but not a Message and no File.  Therefore these checks need to be equivalent and happen at the same level.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
if($text_messege == "hello user"){
```

this will evaluate that $text_message is set to "hello user"

```
if($text_messege){
```

merely evaluates that $text_message is set and is set to something other than null or false.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if(!empty($_FILES['chat_upload_file']) && !empty($text_messege)){
    //both
}else if(!empty($_FILES['chat_upload_file'])){
    //file only
}else if(!empty($text_messege)){
    //message only
}else{
    //nither
}
```

I would probably use `empty` instead of just testing if it's true or false.  Empty will cover undefined index issues you may have.  Without more to go on, I have no way to know if that is a possibility.  For example I have no Idea where `$message` comes from and if it's always considered "set" (or not undefined).

You can optimize this by doing something like this.

```
$file = !empty($_FILES['chat_upload_file']) ? $_FILES['chat_upload_file'] : false;

$text_messege = !empty($text_messege) ? $text_messege : false;

if($file && $text_messege){
    //both
}else if($file){
    //file only
}else if($text_messege){
    //message only
}else{
    //nither
}
```

So you only check empty 2x instead of 4x.

**Original and Issues**

> the condition i want to implement is: when user send both file and text message it will return an error.

You have to (or should) consider 4 possibility (2^2) each variable can have 2 states, well call them on and off

```
  File | Message
   on    on
   on    off
   off   on
   off   off
```

In your original, you are only considering 2 of them

```
  File | Message
   on    on
   on    off
```

Because:

```
if($_FILES['chat_upload_file']){
    if($text_messege){
       //file: on  message: on
    }else{
      //file: on  message: off
    }
}
```

Does not consider what happens when no file is submitted.  And if it's an error to send a File and a Message, then it must be ok to send just a message and no file. Otherwise, you would never be able to send a message (you cant send on with a file, and you cant send one without).  Maybe there is stuff below this? I have no way to know that, though.

It makes little sense to add an else to the outer IF, because you will probably wind up duplicating stuff.

```
if($_FILES['chat_upload_file']){
    if($text_messege){
       //file: on  message: on
    }else{
      //file: on  message: off
    }
}else{
    if($text_messege){
       //file: off  message: on
    }else{
      //file: off  message: off
    }
}
```

And it's a lot cleaner to have 1 control block with 4 conditions, then 3 control blocks with 6 conditions.

It's implied by what you want to do that:

- it's fine to have just a file
- it's fine to have just a message (you don't consider it)
- it's not fine to have both a file and a message
- who knows with neither (you don't consider it)

hope that makes sense.